# How to limit a number between several numbers (get the most nearest small number)?

Tags: javascript, lodash

For example, here is an array like `[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]`
what I want is

```
input: 110 output:100
input: 290 output:200
input: 450 output:400
input: 999 output:500
```

...

Is there a smart way to do it?

Comment: you loop through your sorted array and u stop when the number ahead is greater(meaning the current number is "most nearest small number")

Comment: Since you tagged lodash, the [sortedIndex](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortedIndex) function (minus 1) might be what you want

Comment: @RickyMo   thank you, the lodash way is very smart!